# How to disable a jQuery plugin on WordPress plugin page

Tags: plugin-development, jquery

I have created a WordPress search plugin for a customer. It worked at my site, but when I installed it in my customer's website it broke, because there is a `jquery.formstyller` plugin installed there, which apparently styled the dropdown I used in the plugin with it's own divs and styles.

Is there a way I can turn off that plugin when the user lands on the plugin page for searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

```
/**
 * Dequeue the jQuery UI script.
 *
 * Hooked to the wp_print_scripts action, with a late priority (100),
 * so that it is after the script was enqueued.
 */
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Obviously replace `jquery-ui-core` with the handler of the script you want to remove. And don't do this globaly, only for your plugin page, where conflict happens.

Comment: where can i find the handler of the script?

Comment: Do you know how to use command line tools? `grep -ir "formstyller" wp-content` for example.

Comment: @maztt or you can search for `wp_enqueue_script` which was used to enqueue script in the first place. First parameter is the `$handle` you are looking for.

Comment: the above command will find? and in which command line tool

Comment: @maztt open the project (wp-content) in your favorite editor and do global search. `grep` is the command line tool.

Comment: finally string locator plugin did the trick by which i could find the handler thanks for giving me the insight of the things